# ComboBox Situation in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, checkbox, combobox, show-hide

I have an Excel sheet that's a process checklist. The background is there are 3 Combo Boxes (form control) and within each Combo Box there's multiple options the user can select. Based on what the user selects as a combination between the 3 Combo Boxes it will hide/unhide specific rows in a section and their corresponding checkboxes. I'm trying to code this in VBA.

Between setting everything up these are the problems I'm running into with VBA:

1. There are 60 different ways the user can select options between the 3 Combo Boxes. Including the "Select Option" options (which will be used), the first ComboBox has 5 options, the second 4 options, and the last 3 options. The obvious I've been trying is If/Else logic, but copying and pasting 60 times over seems very redundant and leaves the sheet prone to coding errors that will take time to fix. Is there a better way to code this? Or in the way I'm trying to do this for each change, the If/Else logic is the best way?
2. When coding (I've pasted a short example of part of my code below this section with a few of the cases), I run into "Method and data member not found" or "Invalid use of Me" errors when debugging. How do I fix this?
3. How do I hide and unhide the checkboxes along with the rows be hid and unhidden so the formatting doesn't change and there are not stray checkboxes everywhere?

```
Sub ComboBox1_Change()

'Combo Box 1 is Asset Type, Combo Box 2 is AUS, Combo Box 3 is Transaction Type


'Select, Select, Select OR Refinance

If Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Select Asset Type" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Select AUS" And Me.ComboBox3.Value = "Select Transaction Type" Or Me.ComboBox3.Value = "Refinance" Then
    
    Worksheets("Assets Checklist").Rows("19:37" And "39").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    

'Select, Select, Purchase

ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Select Asset Type" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Select AUS" And Me.ComboBox3.Value = "Purchase" Then

    Worksheets("Assets Checklist").Rows("39").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Assets Checklist").Rows("19:37").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    
    
'Liquid, Select, Select
    
ElseIf Me.ComboBox1.Value = "Liquid" And Me.ComboBox2.Value = "Select AUS" And Me.ComboBox3.Value = "Select Transaction Type" Then

    Worksheets("Assets Checklist").Rows("31:34").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Worksheets("Assets Checklist").Rows("19:30" And "35:37" And "39").EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

And the above code continues for each case.

Comment: If you have 60 distinct cases then the most maintainable method might be to use a worksheet with columns for CB1/2/3 values and a column to hold visible and hidden rows (as range address like "A1:A10,A12", so you can use `me.range(addressHere).EntireRow.Hidden`).  Create a method which reads the values and looks up the matching row on the sheet, then sets the row visibility accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 60 distinct cases then the most maintainable method might be to use a worksheet with columns for CB1/2/3 values and a column to hold visible and hidden rows (as range address like "A1:A10,A12"). Create a method which reads the values and looks up the matching row on the sheet, then sets the row visibility accordingly.

```vb
'this is called from each of the 3 combos
Sub ShowHideRows()
    Dim cb1, cb2, cb3, arr, r As Long, rngHide As String, rngShow As String
    
    cb1 = comboValue("combo1")
    cb2 = comboValue("combo2")
    cb3 = comboValue("combo3")
    Debug.Print cb1, cb2, cb3
    
    arr = Me.Range("choices").Value 'lookup table is a named range
                                    'better on a different sheet....
    For r = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        If arr(r, 1) = cb1 Then
            If arr(r, 2) = cb2 Then
                If arr(r, 3) = cb3 Then
                    rngShow = arr(r, 4)
                    rngHide = arr(r, 5)
                    Exit For 'stop checking
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next r
    
    If rngHide <> "" Then Me.Range(rngHide).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    If rngShow <> "" Then Me.Range(rngShow).EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Sub

'read a Forms combo control value
Function comboValue(cbName As String)
    With Me.Shapes(cbName)
        comboValue = .ControlFormat.List(.ControlFormat.ListIndex)
    End With
End Function
```

Setup:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

'Each of the three Combo Boxes have al Linked Cell
'In an another cell concatenate the numeric values of the three Linced Cells
'e.g. in cell A1 have this: =A2 & A3 & A4
'where A2, A3, and A4 are the Linked cells of CBox1, CBox2 and CBox3
'In every ComboBox value change, call the Sub
'SixtyCases with parameter the value of cell A1

```
Private Sub SixtyCases(combination As String)
   Select Case combination
      Case "111"  'first combination
         'YOUR CODE HERE
      Case "112", "132"  ' OR
         'YOUR CODE HERE
      Case "113"
         'YOUR CODE HERE
         '...
         '...
      Case "543" 'last combination
         'YOUR CODE HERE
   End Select
End Sub
```